# Application Subclass Being Recreated After Being Closed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Have a strange issue with my application and I am unsure what is causing it.

**THE PROBLEM**

I log the important calls in my application to a file so when a user submits a bug report to us I can see exactly what they have done and when.

This, along with the notification appearing as visual confirmation, led me to believe for some reason my class that extends `Application` is being recreated after I close the app.

So in `onCreate` I log that lifecycle method to the file. Bare in mind that when `Service onDestroy` is called that is the last time I close the application before leaving it overnight on charge and the last `Application: onCreate null` is the first time I open it again in the morning.

```
2015-03-11T19:43:47.979Z (24) INFO Service onDestroy
2015-03-11T21:47:34.433Z (24) INFO Application: onCreate null
2015-03-12T02:21:27.236Z (24) INFO Application: onCreate null
2015-03-12T03:10:45.767Z (24) INFO Application: onCreate null
2015-03-12T04:45:08.419Z (24) INFO Application: onCreate null
2015-03-12T06:39:09.433Z (24) INFO Application: onCreate null
```

So as you can see, for some reason onCreate is being called at random intervals when the application goes to background.

**MY SERVICE SETUP**

I start the service when the application launches and call startForeground() in it's `onCreate`. I return `START_STICKY` in it's `onStartCommand`.

When I am finished with the service, I call `stopService` from outside the service and in the service's `onDestroy` I call `stopForeground` along with the id.

I know it's being destroyed because I log when in it's destroyed and when it's created and you can see from above it is not being recreated when the Application is.

**MY MANIFEST**

It is too large to post the entire thing so I have copied areas for concern. The areas I have left off are activities with no other intent filters. The following wear service is new and the issue was happening before this addition so I don't believe this is causing it.

```
<!-- Cannot set android:exported to false otherwise this service does not work.-->
        <service android:name=".appwear.WearableListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Following receiver is called when the notification's action, started by the foreground service, is pressed.

```
        <receiver android:name=".recording.NotificationReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.notif.pauserecording"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.notif.startrecording"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<provider
            android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider#"
            android:exported="true" />
```

My foreground service.

```
<service android:name=".recording.LocationTrackingService" />

<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.logprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

**MY THOUGHTS**

Could it be that somewhere in my application I am forgetting to unregister a broadcast receiver or removing a listener? A have done one thorough check but there is a chance I missed something.

Is there something about the lifecycle I'm not understanding? Is the `Application` meant to do this? According to the documentation the `Application`'s `onCreate` method is...

> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service,
>   or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.
>   Implementations should be as quick as possible (for example using lazy
>   initialization of state) since the time spent in this function
>   directly impacts the performance of starting the first activity,
>   service, or receiver in a process. If you override this method, be
>   sure to call super.onCreate()

Comment: Are you using any `service`? It may  be possible that it calls your `onCreate()` method

Comment: The only `service` I am using is started at runtime. I don't have any services started using intent filters in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

considering the amount of information/code you gave, any answer will be a "best guess".

So my informed best guess is:

- you're starting this service as `start_sticky`
- all your activities goes to background or are destroyed, the only thing running is your service.
- you never called `stopSelf();` on the service
- the OS needs to do some stuff like update apps, synchronize data, etc.
- the OS kills your application completely to do its stuff.
- the OS re-creates your Application and re-starts the service.

Those are the logs you see!

Unfortunately the system can do those stuff and not always inform you about it all, please check the documentation on [`Service.START_STICKY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY):

> Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this
>   service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state
>   but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to
>   re-create the service. Because it is in the started state, it will
>   guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after creating the
>   new service instance; if there are not any pending start commands to
>   be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent
>   object, so you must take care to check for this.

**Edit:**

With the extra manifest information you posted I would point to:

> `WearableListenerService`: Receives events from other nodes, such as
>   data changes, messages or connectivity events.

but the only way to know for sure is either putting some Log there, or removing it. Either way, it will need test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am starting it as start_sticky, however I call `stopForeground()` in it's onDestroy. It's stopped when the application goes into background and it's not recording. When the service starts I log that too, so it's not being restarted. I will add this info to my original question

Comment: from my experience, anything that is starting your application is inside there. You can either post it for us to check, OR make sure that you have a LOG on every single element of that manifest and test for yourself.

Comment: I have added parts of the manifest that could be causing the issue. The rest are just activities without intent filters and permissions

Comment: I've added some extra thoughts to my answer.